# Are there third party vendors supporting Azure AD B2C with a native mobile experience that does not rely on ROPC or require an authenticator app?

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, biometrics, password-less

Have a Xamarin.Forms app relying on Azure AD B2C for auth. B2C does not offer a native login experience, or direct support for biometric logins. Vendors like Nevis and Keyless both appear to require their own application to be used to support biometric logins. Are there vendors that offer an API or SDK for biometric and direct password handling, without relying on ROPC flow?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you usually use ROPC as initial auth, then protect subsequent access via biometric by wrapping the devices biometric SDK around the MSAL authentication calls.

```
If (device biometric challenge satisfied)  
{  
acquireTokenSilent()  
}
```